# How can I use a variable in unmanagedJars path in sbt 0.13.8?

Tags: scala, sbt

I tried doing this but it didn't work.

```
val buildType = "test"

unmanagedJars in Compile += file(s"../${buildType}/helper.jar")

If I hardcode the path like this, then it works fine:

unmanagedJars in Compile += file("../test/helper.jar")
```

Can I write scala code in a sbt file?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this works fine, I think I wasn't declaring the buildType val before.